# Does an Object's TCriticalSection block calls from multiple threads to multiple locked methods?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to track down an issue that I believe exists with an object's global TCriticalSection.  Example code:

```
TMyObject = class
private
 FCS: TCriticalSection;
 FInternalObject: TSomeInternalObject;
public
 constructor Create;
 destructor Destroy; override;
 procedure WorkWithObjectA(Data: TDataTypeA);
 procedure WorkWithObjectB(Data: TDataTypeB);
end;

constructor TMyObject.Create;
begin
 FCS := TCriticalSection.Create;
 FInternalObject := TSomeInternalObject.Create;
end;

destructor TMyObject.Destroy;
begin
 FInternalObject.Free;
 FCS.Free;
 inherited;
end;

procedure TMyObject.WorkWithObjectA(Data: TDataTypeA);
begin
 FCS.Enter;
 try
  FInternalObject.DoProcessA(Data);
 finally
  FCS.Leave;
end;

procedure TMyObject.WorkWithObjectB(Data: TDataTypeB);
begin
 FCS.Enter;
 try
  FInternalObject.DoProcessB(Data);
 finally
  FCS.Leave;
end;
```

Question: If multiple threads are calling both procedures, will the TCriticalSection block WorkWithObjectB() if WorkWithObjectA() is blocking? This is a simplified version of a much more complex situation.  The two procedures use greatly different structures, and thus cannot be easily combined into one blocking method... thoughts?

Comment: Yes. You use the same critical section in both procedures (FCS) so the code in only one instance of either of them across all threads will get past `.Enter` at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if multiple threads are calling both procedures, the TCriticalSection will block both WorkWithObjectB() and WorkWithObjectA().

Note that in a complex situation, where WorkWithObjectB() will call WorkWithObjectA(), then there will be no deadlock. The lock occurs only when the call is in the context of a thread not already owning the lock.

Comment: Perfect... I thought this was the case, but in my debugging I wanted to rule it out completely.  Thanks!

Comment: Assume the same code above.  If two DLLs are using callbacks to access WorkWithObjectA() and WorkWithObjectB() respectively, is there a possibility that the DLLs do not have visibility into the lock status?  That is, could two DLLs make a call to WorkWithObjectA() and not be held by the lock?  We ask this since within the main code, the locks appear to be preventing simultaneous access, but when a thread running inside a dynamically loaded DLL makes the call (via a callback), the result pointer of the function appears corrupted leading us to believe the thread is not being held by the lock.

Comment: Accessing objects from a DLL loaded by an EXE requires that both exe and dll are using the same object, that is the a package (Winch is also a DLL with a layer to make it object aware). Without packages, the object are not the same altough their type is the same.

Comment: The call is message based - that is the callback provides a pointer to a record structure.  A DLL manager handles the messages and passes the record pointer to the object (which contains the critical section locks) - but the execution remains in the DLL's thread. The object uses ActiveX libraries, so we think this might be a CoInitialize issue or the DLL's thread is ignoring the lock - one or the other. Weirdly it works on our development machines (Windows 10 based) but fails on one VPS running Windows Server 2016 which leads us to believe that memory is affected.

Comment: Using the `is` operator, verify that the object instance your code manipulate is of the expected type. Without package if your EXE pass an TMyObject instance (In Delphi, this is a pointer) to a DLL, the DLL won't consider it as a TMyObject altought the same unit defining TMyObject are used in both the EXE and the DLL.

Comment: The pointer is to a record that is globally defined, not an object.  The record is local to the calling routine (that performs the callback to the main code from the DLL).  The problem doesn't appear to be CoInitialize,.  DLL is accessing an ADO object so the only thing that we can assume is that the lock is not stopping the thread from proceeding causing corruption of the memory either in the ADO connection object or somewhere else.  Since it occurs on some machines and not others, it's probably memory corruption.  We see access violations in NTDLL.DLL and the MySQL DLLs.  We'll keep looking.

Comment: Your question is related to object, not record. Since this website doesn't accept that we chat around your question, I suggest you create a new question which correctly describe the issue and his context. Add to the question a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With such example, we will be able to reproduce your problem, understand it and try to solve it.

Comment: Agreed.  The source code above and the original question are accepted.  We did find the issue that started this thread and it was unrelated to the critical section, but rather the use of ADO objects in multithreaded applications.  Thanks again!